# UK Tax Calculator - First Python program

Tags: python, python-2.x, tkinter

This is my first Python program and while it's not quite finished I would like to know how I could improve in general as a programmer. This project has be a lot of fun but it has felt more like throwing stuff at the wall and seeing what sticks rather than well thought out programming.

Could anyone point out things I'm doing very wrong?

Also I feel like all the code is in just this one file is that a problem it makes the code a bit hard to read, I did try separating out the Tkinker widgets code from the function that runs the calculations but that meant i had to do some circular imports and it didn't like that.

I also understand that I have commented none of my code - I apologies for this. I was planning on doing that at some point.

Any constructive feedback would be great.

```
#!/user
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import math
import locale
import Tkinter as Tk

locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, '')
root = Tk.Tk()
root.title("My Tax Calculator")
root.geometry("700x225")

TaxFreeNum = 11850


def getStudentLoan():
    global StudentLoan
    StudentLoan = StudentLoanOp.get()
    print StudentLoan

def callback():
    GetGrossTax = GrossTaxIn.get()
    GrossYear = float(GetGrossTax)
    GrossMonth = GrossYear / 12
    GrossWeek = GrossYear / 52
    GrossDay = GrossYear / 260

    if StudentLoan == "Plan 1":
        if GrossYear >= 18331:
            PlanThreshold = 18330
            Plan = (GrossYear - PlanThreshold)*0.09
            Plan1Li = Tk.Label(RightFrame, text='£{:,.2f}'.format(Plan))
            Plan1Li.grid(row=7, column=1)
    elif StudentLoan == "Plan 2":
        if GrossYear >= 25001:
            PlanThreshold = 25001
            Plan = (GrossYear - PlanThreshold)*0.09
            Plan2Li = Tk.Label(RightFrame, text='£{:,.2f}'.format(Plan))
            Plan2Li.grid(row=7, column=1)
    else:
        NoPlan = Tk.Label(RightFrame, text="£0.00")
        NoPlan.grid(row=7, column=1)
        Plan = 0

    Yearli = Tk.Label(RightFrame, text='£{:,.2f}'.format(GrossYear))
    Yearli.grid(row=1, column=1)
    Monthli = Tk.Label(RightFrame, text='£{:,.2f}'.format(GrossMonth))
    Monthli.grid(row=1, column=2)
    Weekli = Tk.Label(RightFrame, text='£{:,.2f}'.format(GrossWeek))
    Weekli.grid(row=1, column=3)
    Dayli = Tk.Label(RightFrame, text='£{:,.2f}'.format(GrossDay))
    Dayli.grid(row=1, column=4)

    TaxFreeYear = Tk.Label(RightFrame, text='£{:,.2f}'.format(TaxFreeNum))
    TaxFreeYear.grid(row=2, column=1)
    TaxFreeMonth = Tk.Label(RightFrame, text='£{:,.2f}'.format(TaxFreeNum / 12))
    TaxFreeMonth.grid(row=2, column=2)
    TaxFreeWeek = Tk.Label(RightFrame, text='£{:,.2f}'.format(TaxFreeNum / 52))
    TaxFreeWeek.grid(row=2, column=3)
    TaxFreeDay = Tk.Label(RightFrame, text='£{:,.2f}'.format(TaxFreeNum / 260))
    TaxFreeDay.grid(row=2, column=4)

    if GrossYear > 11850:
        TotalTaxableYear = Tk.Label(RightFrame, text='£{:,.2f}'.format(GrossYear - TaxFreeNum))
        TotalTaxableYear.grid(row=3, column=1)
        TotalTaxableMonth = Tk.Label(RightFrame, text='£{:,.2f}'.format(GrossMonth - TaxFreeNum / 12))
        TotalTaxableMonth.grid(row=3, column=2)
        TotalTaxableWeekly = Tk.Label(RightFrame, text='£{:,.2f}'.format(GrossWeek - TaxFreeNum / 52))
        TotalTaxableWeekly.grid(row=3, column=3)
        TotalTaxableDaily = Tk.Label(RightFrame, text='£{:,.2f}'.format(GrossDay - TaxFreeNum / 365))
        TotalTaxableDaily.grid(row=3, column=4)
    else:
        TotalTaxableYear = Tk.Label(RightFrame, text='£0.00')
        TotalTaxableYear.grid(row=3, column=1)
        TotalTaxableMonth = Tk.Label(RightFrame, text='£0.00')
        TotalTaxableMonth.grid(row=3, column=2)
        TotalTaxableWeekly = Tk.Label(RightFrame, text='£0.00')
        TotalTaxableWeekly.grid(row=3, column=3)
        TotalTaxableDaily = Tk.Label(RightFrame, text='£0.00')
        TotalTaxableDaily.grid(row=3, column=4)

    if GrossYear > 150000:
        AdditionalRate = GrossYear - 150000
        AdditionalRateTax = Tk.Label(RightFrame, text='£{:,.2f}'.format(AdditionalRate*0.45))
        AdditionalRateTax.grid(row=6, column=1)
        HigherRate = Tk.Label(RightFrame, text='£{:,.2f}'.format(103649*0.40))
        HigherRate.grid(row=5,column=1)
        BasicRate = Tk.Label(RightFrame, text='£{:,.2f}'.format(34449*0.20))
        BasicRate.grid(row=4, column=1)
        TotalIn = (34449*0.20) + (103649*0.40) + (AdditionalRate*0.45)
    elif GrossYear <= 150000 and GrossYear >= 46351:
        HigherRate = GrossYear - 46351
        HigherRateTax = Tk.Label(RightFrame, text='£{:,.2f}'.format(HigherRate*0.40))
        HigherRateTax.grid(row=5, column=1)
        BasicRate = Tk.Label(RightFrame, text='£{:,.2f}'.format(34449 * 0.20))
        BasicRate.grid(row=4, column=1)
        AdditionalRateTax = Tk.Label(RightFrame, text='£0.00')
        AdditionalRateTax.grid(row=6, column=1)
        TotalIn= (34449*0.20) + (HigherRate*0.40)
    elif GrossYear <=46350 and GrossYear >=11851:
        BasicRate = GrossYear - 11851
        BasicRateTax = Tk.Label(RightFrame, text='£{:,.2f}'.format(BasicRate*0.20))
        BasicRateTax.grid(row=4, column=1)
        HigherRateTax = Tk.Label(RightFrame, text='£0.00')
        HigherRateTax.grid(row=5, column=1)
        AdditionalRateTax = Tk.Label(RightFrame, text='£0.00')
        AdditionalRateTax.grid(row=6, column=1)
        TotalIn = (BasicRate*0.20)
    else:
        TotalIn = 0


    if GrossYear >= 46384:
        netTax = GrossYear - 8424
        LowerNi = 37960 * 0.12
        HigherNi = GrossYear - 46384
        HigherNiTax = (HigherNi * 0.02)
        TotalNi = HigherNiTax + LowerNi
        TotalNiLi = Tk.Label(RightFrame, text='£{:,.2f}'.format(TotalNi))
        TotalNiLi.grid(row=8, column=1)
    elif GrossYear >8424 and GrossYear <46384:
        netTax = GrossYear - 8428
        TotalNi = (netTax * 0.12)
        TotalNiLi = Tk.Label(RightFrame, text='£{:,.2f}'.format(TotalNi))
        TotalNiLi.grid(row=8, column=1)
    else:
        TotalNi = 0

    TotalNetTax = round((TotalNi) + (TotalIn) + (Plan),2)
    TotalNetTaxLi = Tk.Label(RightFrame,text='£{:,.2f}'.format(TotalNetTax))
    TotalNetTaxLi.grid(row=9, column=1)

    TotalNetWages = GrossYear - TotalNetTax
    TotalNetWagesMonthly = TotalNetWages / 12
    TotalNetWagesWeekly = TotalNetWages / 52
    TotalNetWagesDaily = TotalNetWages / 260
    TotalNetWagesLi = Tk.Label(RightFrame,text='£{:,.2f}'.format(TotalNetWages))
    TotalNetWagesLi.grid(row=10, column=1)
    TotalNetWagesMonthlyLi = Tk.Label(RightFrame, text='£{:,.2f}'.format(TotalNetWagesMonthly))
    TotalNetWagesMonthlyLi.grid(row=10, column=2)
    TotalNetWagesWeeklyLi = Tk.Label(RightFrame, text='£{:,.2f}'.format(TotalNetWagesWeekly))
    TotalNetWagesWeeklyLi.grid(row=10, column=3)
    TotalNetWagesDailyLi = Tk.Label(RightFrame, text='£{:,.2f}'.format(TotalNetWagesDaily))
    TotalNetWagesDailyLi.grid(row=10, column=4)


LeftFrame = Tk.Frame(root, width=300, height=200, pady=3)
RightFrame = Tk.Frame(root, width=400, height=200, pady=3)

LeftFrame.grid(sticky="n", row=0, column=0)
RightFrame.grid(sticky="n", row=0, column=1)

TaxYearOp = Tk.StringVar()
TaxYearOp.set("2018/2019")  # default value

StudentLoanOp = Tk.StringVar()
StudentLoanOp.set("No")

TaxYear = Tk.Label(LeftFrame, text="Select tax year")
TaxYear.grid(row=1, column=0)

Placeholder = Tk.Label(LeftFrame, text="")
Placeholder.grid(row=1, column=1)

TaxYearLi = Tk.OptionMenu(Placeholder, TaxYearOp, "2018/2019")
TaxYearLi.grid(row=1, column=1)

StudentLoan = Tk.Label(LeftFrame, text="Repay Student Loan?")
StudentLoan.grid(row=2, column=0)

Placeholder2 = Tk.Label(LeftFrame, text="")
Placeholder2.grid(row=2, column=1)

StudentLoanLi = Tk.OptionMenu(Placeholder2, StudentLoanOp, "No", "Plan 1", "Plan 2", command=lambda _: getStudentLoan())
StudentLoanLi.grid(row=2, column=1)

Pension = Tk.Label(LeftFrame, text="Pension contributions (£ or %)")
Pension.grid(row=3, column=0)

PensionEn = Tk.Entry(LeftFrame)
PensionEn.grid(row=3, column=1)

GrossTaxLa = Tk.Label(LeftFrame, text="Pre-Tax earnings here! >")
GrossTaxLa.grid(row=4, column=0)

GrossTaxIn = Tk.Entry(LeftFrame)
GrossTaxIn.grid(row=4, column=1)

TaxCalGo = Tk.Button(LeftFrame, text="Calculate My Wage", command=callback)
TaxCalGo.grid(row=5, column=1)

Summary = Tk.Label(RightFrame, text="Salary Summary", width=15)
Summary.grid(row=0, column=0)
Yearly = Tk.Label(RightFrame, text="Year", width=10)
Yearly.grid(row=0, column=1)
Monthly = Tk.Label(RightFrame, text="Monthly", width=10)
Monthly.grid(row=0, column=2)
Weekly = Tk.Label(RightFrame, text="Weekly", width=10)
Weekly.grid(row=0, column=3)
Daily = Tk.Label(RightFrame, text="Daily", width=10)
Daily.grid(row=0, column=4)

Summary = Tk.Label(RightFrame, text="Salary Summary", width=15)
Summary.grid(row=0, column=0)
GrossPay = Tk.Label(RightFrame, text="Gross Pay", width=15)
GrossPay.grid(row=1, column=0)
TaxFree = Tk.Label(RightFrame, text="Tax Free Allowance", width=15)
TaxFree.grid(row=2, column=0)
TotalTaxable = Tk.Label(RightFrame, text="Total Taxable", width=15)
TotalTaxable.grid(row=3, column=0)
Tax20 = Tk.Label(RightFrame, text="20% rate", width=15)
Tax20.grid(row=4, column=0)
Tax40 = Tk.Label(RightFrame, text="40% rate", width=15)
Tax40.grid(row=5, column=0)
Tax45 = Tk.Label(RightFrame, text="45% rate", width=15)
Tax45.grid(row=6, column=0)
StudentTax = Tk.Label(RightFrame, text="Student Loan", width=15)
StudentTax.grid(row=7, column=0)
NI = Tk.Label(RightFrame, text="National Insurance", width=15)
NI.grid(row=8, column=0)
TotalDeductions = Tk.Label(RightFrame, text="Total Deductions", width=15)
TotalDeductions.grid(row=9, column=0)
NetWage = Tk.Label(RightFrame, text="Net Wage", width=15)
NetWage.grid(row=10, column=0)

Tk.mainloop()
```

Comment: (Welcome to Code Review!) Does this program run without errors? I'm pretty sure you have to call `root.mainloop()` instead.

Comment: @coal yes this program runs without any errors

Comment: a general tip would be to put organise the code in functions, and separate the calculation from the presentation. That would be a huge improvement already

Comment: If you've just started with Python I also advise you to use Python 3 instead of 2.7.